# Ignore DataMember in Fluent Assertions.ShouldBeEquivalentTo

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I'm using the [FluentAssertions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions/) library to verify serialization is working as expected using the DataContractSerializer.

Many of the objects I'm serializing have  `[IgnoreDataMember]` attributes on some properties.

Is there a a way to instruct fluent assertions to disregard ignored data members when performing a `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` assertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.Excluding(info => info.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes().Any()));

The `info` object is of type `ISubjectInfo` and provides all kinds of information about the involved properties.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this answer not work (any more)? Also: `info` is not of type `ISubjectInfo`..

Comment: There were quite some breaking changes in [5.0](https://www.continuousimprover.com/2018/02/fluent-assertions-50-best-unit-test.html).

Comment: I suspected so. However I fail to find the new way of solving the problem. The best thing I came up with is serializing both objects and compare the results.

Comment: In 5.0, the syntax has changed to `actual.Should().BeEquivalent()`. The rest of the options are the same.